# into near darkness

Tags: determiners

This sentence is from a medieval fantasy book, Cold Iron by Miles Cameron:

> He rode down a farm lane and well around the soldiers, and emerged on the turnpike into near darkness.

I was wondering why it isn't "into the near darkness" instead of "into near darkness"?

Comment: Why do you think it should be 'the near darkness'?

Comment: Because I've always seen "darkness" used after "the".

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would write 'the near darkness' if we are referring to a specific near darkness, e.g. the near darkness of something, somewhere, or a time of day, such as the near darkness of an old house, or of an early winter evening. The writer is just referring to generic, non-specific, near darkness. Compare 'from darkness into sunshine'.